# restart workers messenger with symfony and supervisord

Tags: symfony, supervisord

I'm actually mounting a Docker for my company, I'm using a phpfpm container and I put inside supervisord. Supervisor start my phpfpm service and my symfony's workers to consume when I send messages with messenger. But I have a problem in my local environment ... I have to execute manually the following command everytime I update my code locally : `php bin/console messenger:stop-workers`

I start my workers like that:

```
[program:messenger-consume-sandbox]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php bin/console messenger:consume sandbox -vv --time-limit=7200
user=root
numprocs=2
startsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
```

I'm looking for a solution with supervisord to watch the code everytime and execute the command above but actually I found nothing.

if someone has some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/18-async.html#running-workers-in-the-background), the `messenger:consume` command can be delegated to the [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download) that would watch for the file system changes and auto-restart the workers.

For example, `supervisord.conf` would look like this:

```
[program:messenger-consume-sandbox]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=symfony run --watch=config,src,templates,vendor symfony console messenger:consume sandbox -vv
```